# Symfony Forms - Datatime Add +30minutes

Tags: forms, symfony

When I set beginAt(DateTime) in Forms I would like set the same date in the "endAt" but +30 minutes. I have no clu how to do this :(

The first code is the part Form in my project and the second code is function "new Appointment" to add appointment.

```
$builder
                ->add('title', TextType::class, ['label'=>'Tytuł'])
                ->add('description', TextType::class, ['label'=>'Treść'])
                ->add('beginAt')
                ->add('endAt')


            ;



public function new(Request $request, $id, TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage): Response
    {
        $currentUser = $tokenStorage->getToken()
                ->getUser();

        $username = $currentUser->getUsername();

        $appointment = new Appointments();
        $appointment->setDoctor($id);
        $appointment->setUsername($username);
        $form = $this->createForm(AppointmentsType::class, $appointment);

        $form->handleRequest($request);


        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($appointment);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('przychodnia_index');
        }


        return $this->render('appointments/new.html.twig', [
            'appointment' => $appointment,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: you already successfully used texttype. does this help you with the dates? https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/datetime.html

Comment: Do you want to set endAt dynamically just after the user selected beginAt for example with javascript?

Comment: @QuentinDequippe Exacly!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Symfony Form Events](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html) to update endAt field on submit for example and use some ajax to submit your form dynamically. There is a great tutorial here (in French sorry) https://www.grafikart.fr/tutoriels/champs-imbriques-888